# How to loop through Oracle Page Items varying item names with loop iteration

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Apex 4.2 page with four page items:
:P236_Author1_last_name
:P236_Author2_last_name
:P236_Author3_last_name
:P236_Author4_last_name

Similarly, My table has the fields:
AUTHOR1_LAST_NAME
AUTHOR2_LAST_NAME
AUTHOR3_LAST_NAME
AUTHOR4_LAST_NAME

I'd like to create a page process to reference the item within a loop.  Something like:

```
Declare
  l_author_last_name varchar2(512);
  l_column_name varchar2(512);
  l_prim_key number;
Begin
  For i In 1..4 
  Loop
    l_author_last_name := ':P236_AUTHOR' || i || '_LAST_NAME'; 
    l_column_name := 'AUTHOR' || i || 'LAST_NAME';
    --Processing to determine the value of l_prim_key
    Update my_table
      Set l_column_name = l_author_last_name
      Where my_table.prim_key = l_prim_key;
    -- More processing here referencing l_author_last_name
  End Loop;
End;
```

How do I go about looping through page items that are differentiated only by the loop iteration number?
Many thanks for looking at this.
Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about storing the values of your items in a collection then looping through that collection? And consider using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` if you're referring to a column name or a table name through variables. Here's a revision of your code:

```
Declare
  type my_collection is table of varchar2(512);
  collection_of_lastname my_collection := my_collection(:P236_Author1_last_name,:P236_Author2_last_name,:P236_Author3_last_name,:P236_Author4_last_name);
  l_author_last_name varchar2(512);
  l_column_name varchar2(512);
  l_prim_key number;
Begin
  For i In 1..collection_of_lastname.count
  Loop
    l_author_last_name := collection_of_lastname(i); 
    l_column_name := 'AUTHOR' || i || 'LAST_NAME';
    --Processing to determine the value of l_prim_key
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Update my_table
      Set ' || l_column_name || '=''' || l_author_last_name || 
      ''' Where my_table.prim_key = ' || l_prim_key;
    -- More processing here referencing l_author_last_name
  End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: Hi Vance,  Thanks very much for replying.  It works perfectly!  I really appreciate the help.  Phil